# How do I test the WDK 8.1 scanner file system minifilter driver sample?

Tags: driver, wdk, minifilter

I downloaded the WDK 8.1 and samples and using Win 7 Debug Win32 build configuration while building with Visual Studio 2013 for the "Scanner File System Minifilter Driver" sample solution. It successfully built the solution.

The build output 3 files of interest to me:

1) scanner.sys (the scanner file system minifilter driver)
2) scanuser.exe (the user-land executable that talked to the driver)
3) scanner.inf (driver installation file)

I copied the files over to my VMware virtual machine (XP 32-bit, in this case) and installed the driver using the .inf file which put the appropriate registry keys in the registry and put a copy of the .sys file into C:\Windows\System32\drivers. Then I ran "net start scanner" which started the driver successfully.

So far, this all worked fine. However ...

When I ran the scanuser.exe file it says it's not a valid Win32 application.

How do I go about testing this if I can't run the executable?

Are there build options I have to set in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Visual Studio 2013 will not produce executable that will run on Windows XP.

You must change the [platform toolset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx):

> In the Property Pages dialog box for the project, under Configuration Properties, General, set the Platform Toolset property to the desired Windows XP toolset. For example, choose Visual Studio 2012 – Windows XP (v110_xp) to create code that is binary compatible with the Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable libraries.

In a similar project, I used the Visual Studio 2010 toolset.

Comment: It does not build if I change this for the scanuser project within the solution. If I change it back to what it was originally: "WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1" then it builds. How do I build it with that property set?

Comment: I think I might actually not be able to use WDK 8.1 and have to use an older version of the WDK to make a driver for XP?